# c# datagridview 'if' condition for count based on previous column not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im still a c# beginner, Im trying to count how many '1' is in `status_id`, and then count `dept_id` with 1 or 4 or 5 based on status_id
So basically 'status_id' if '1' means its open, I want to know its open in which dept.
But the if condition is not working.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var count = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
       .Count(row => row.Cells["status_id"].Value.ToString() == "1");

    if (dataGridView1.Rows[count - 1].Cells["status_id"].Value.ToString() == "1")
    {
        var general = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
       .Count(row => row.Cells["dept_id"].Value.ToString() == "1");
        this.textBox2.Text = general.ToString();
    }
```

This is an example of the code for first part 'general' and the rest is the same for 'finance' and 'tech'

[image: Example of script]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the following line `if (dataGridView1.Rows[count - 1].Cells["status_id"].Value.ToString() == "1")` ? To be precise I want to know why `[count - 1]`? Imaging you have the following data - 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 and get the Count for 1 - so 3, now you get the count - 1 so 3 - 1 = 2 and you get the row with the index 2 - with that you will get the 3rd row with its value 2. - that doesn't seem correct

Comment: @RandRandom im trying to count the dept_id column based only if its corresponding value in status_id is 1
Im still a beginner but following a specific tutorial it mentioned the count -1
do u think i should remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get all rows in your dataGrid that have a 1 in status_id
    var foundRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Cells["status_id"].Value.ToString() == "1");

    //get the count of the found rows
    var count = foundRows.Count(); 

    //in the foundRows search further/deeper for rows that have a 1 in dept_id - this will give rows that have both status_id = 1 AND dept_id = 1
    var foundChildRows = foundRows.Where(row => row.Cells["dept_id"].Value.ToString() == "1");

    //get the count of the found"Child"Rows
    var childCount = foundChildRows.Count();
    this.textBox2.Text = childCount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems weird the me: on the first line you count the rows with a status equal to 1. For example you find 3 rows with that status.

Then you get the row at the position of the found count (so in my example you would get the 3rd row) and if the status of that row equals to 1 you perform the code in the if block (count all rows with dept_id equal to 1).

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but I guess that you don't want to refer to the n-th row where n is based on the status count?

Comment: Im trying to count how many rows have 1
if it has 1 it displays in a textbox the total, then i want to know that 1 from status_id has which code beside it (1,4,5) and then display in a different textbox